# Python - Using recursion to find out the content of a string

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

So I am trying to figure out an algorithm to guess a given word, such that the program ends when my guessing word matches the correct word. Using iteration it is intuitive that a nested for loop statement should be used, how every it is **very** ineffective because for each letter in the guessing word we would need a for statement. For a 2 char long string it would look like this:

```py
import string
import time

correct = 'zz'
guess = ''
chars = [char for char in string.printable]
start_time = time.time()

for i in chars:
    for j in chars:
        guess = str(i)+str(j)
        if guess == correct:
            print("I guessed the string: "+guess)
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            exit()

print("I couldn't guess the string!")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

However for it to be of variable length, I am pretty sure I need to use a recursive function to handle this, but I could not come to an answer. This problem is like a neural network with N layers where N is the length of the string to guess. I'm not sure what my single function is supposed to actually do, whether just checking a "layer" of the network and calling it N times or whether it should perform N layers directly. Anybody can kindly help?

Comment: Are you trying to make an algorithm that guesses a word?

Comment: So you want a method that takes builds a string until it matches a given one ? Do it letter by letter and use the recursion in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is not allowed to check the guess character by character, thus you have to compute the whole guess to be able to check it.

You can do this recursively, by carrying an accumulator around that represents the current guess. As soon as we reach the desired length, compare to the correct string.

```
def guess(correct, old_guess=""):
    # iterate through all possible chars
    for char in string.printable:
        # append new char to accumulator
        new_guess = old_guess + char
        # if we reach correct length
        if len(correct) == len(new_guess):
            # compare guess to correct string
            if new_guess == correct:
                # return the correct guess
                return new_guess
            else:
                # try other characters
                continue
        else:
            # continue with next character
            result = guess(correct, new_guess)
            # if this led to success, skip the other characters and return guess
            if result:
                return res
    # if no character led to the correct guess, return None
    return None
```

Keep in mind, that already for short strings, this leads to a long computation time, as the required effort grows exponentially with the number of characters in the correct string.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's so annoying to waste like an hour thinking recursively and not coming up with a solution.